# Call javascript from Iframe to aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have two pages `a.aspx` and `b.aspx`. `a.aspx` have an `Iframe` and I load the `b.aspx` page in that `Iframe`. Is it possible to call a `javascript` from `b.aspx` to `a.aspx`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: show your code which you have done so far

Comment: Do you mean iFrame?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, which will also cover scenarios where you've got different origins for the outer page and the page in the IFrame (e.g. `http://site1/a.aspx` and `http://site2/b.aspx`) is to use the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) function.

This has the added advantage that you're "locking yourself in" to an API contract between `a.aspx` and `b.aspx` as, if you had a function called `DoSomething` in `b.apx` which was being called from `a.aspx`, if you decided to rename the function you'd need to make changes to both pages (and any other pages that hosted `a.aspx` in an IFrame). If you use the `postMessage` approach, the only place you'd need to change would be the listener for the "message" event in `b.aspx`.

If you put the following code in `a.aspx`:

```
function sendMessageToEveryIFrame(message)
{
    /// <summary>Call a function against all frames</summary>
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var frame = frames[i];

            frame.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            // Code to handle errors would go here!
        }
    }
}
```

You could then call it (perhaps on a button click for testing purposes) by having:

```
sendMessageToEveryIFrame('Test message!');
```

You then need some code in `b.aspx` that reacts to messages coming in, for example:

```
// This wires up your function that processes the message
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
    // logic that reacts to the event/message goes here
    alert(event.data);
}
```

When you press the button in `a.aspx` in the browser (or whatever else you're using to trigger the call) `b.aspx` should pop up an alert window containing the text "Test message!".

Your `receiveMessage` function can then dispatch the request and effectively act as a broker. So, if you had two functions inside `b.aspx` that you wanted to call, you could re-jig the code like this:

In `a.aspx`:

```
function callFrameFunction(functionName, parameters)
{
    /// <summary>Call a function against all frames</summary>
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var frame = frames[i];

            var message =
                {
                    Function: function,
                    Parameters : parameters
                };
            frame.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            // Code to handle errors would go here!
        }
    }
}
```

This means that `callFrameFunction` takes two parameters, the name of a function and the parameters for the function. You'd then update the code in `b.aspx` so that it looks more like this:

```
// This wires up your function that processes the message
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
    // logic that reacts to the event/message goes here
    switch(event.data.FunctionName)
    {
        case "function 1":
            alert('Function called was \'function 1\'');
            break;
        case "function 2":
            alert('Function called was \'function 2\'');
            break;
    }
}
```

You can replace the calls to `alert` with calls to your functions, passing in the values in `event.data.Parameters` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following javascript function in `b.aspx`.

```
function DoSomething()
{
   //Do you required tasks
}
```

And you want to call this function in `a.aspx`. `a.aspx` has `b.aspx` loaded in and iframe as follows.

```
<iframe  id="fraExample" name="fraExample" scrolling="no"  src="b.aspx"></iframe>
```

This is how you'll call function **DoSomething** written in `b.aspx` from a function written in `a.aspx`

```
function CallFunction()
{
    // This function will be in a.aspx
    // some tasks

    var bFrame = document.getElementById('fraExample'); // Get the iframe
    bFrame.contentWindow.DoSomething();

    // some other tasks
}
```

This should work for you nice and easy!